# How can I do jointure in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I need to do a jointure between 2 tables to have all fields from Sleep and latlong from Poi.

How can I do ? with Join or with Includes

```
@sleeps = Sleep.where(track_id: track).includes(:poi)

@sleeps = Sleep.where(track_id: track).joins(:poi)
```

What's the difference beetwen the both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `.includes` is left join whereas a `.join` is an inner join.  Note: you may need to add a reference to effectively complete a left join as one query (internal optimizations often default to 2 queries for includes alone) e.g.:

```
Sleep.includes(:poi).references(:poi).where(...)
```